# How can I get usage data for the google cloud vision api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I was wondering if it would be possible to programmatically find out how many times an api has been used. The api usage page on the project in the console is perpetually reporting zero usage and the quota's page is a bit delayed but does report how much usage occurred that day. Ideally, I'm looking for an api I could call to tell me how many of each type of request has occurred that month so I can determine how much I am going to be billed.

Comment: I'm currently doing this using a Selenium-based web scraper. I would love to find an API that reports this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Audit Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/) for this. I export my logs to BigQuery and then query them for usage. There is a tutorial on how to set this up [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs), though the example queries are for the deprecated version 1.